# MacOS: "No module named 'pandas'"

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to learn pandas but I got stuck on importing the module.

I got this error message:
[terminal screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXKgy.png)

I checked if :

- pandas is installed - yes
- conda and python are installed in the same directory - yes
- python version is 3.x - yes

I would be glad if you could help.

Comment: in which ide you are running python code?

Comment: By the first line of what is printed when you run `python` in your terminal, it does not look like an anaconda installed one to me. Do you have, by any chance, an `alias` defined for `python`?

Comment: yes I have an alias "python" for python3

Comment: Please add how you have checked the version of Python and pandas is installed, e.g. `which python` or `python --version` and post the output.

Comment: (base) Szymons-MacBook-Air:~ ssosulski$ python --version
Python 3.8.2
(base) Szymons-MacBook-Air:~ ssosulski$ conda --version
conda 4.8.3
(base) Szymons-MacBook-Air:~ ssosulski$ pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
(base) Szymons-MacBook-Air:~ ssosulski$ which python
/Users/ssosulski/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
(base) Szymons-MacBook-Air:~ ssosulski$ which conda
/Users/ssosulski/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda

Comment: (base) Szymons-MacBook-Air:~ ssosulski$ which pip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pip

Comment: What does `conda list pandas` tell?

Comment: # packages in environment at /Users/ssosulski/opt/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pandas                    1.0.1            py37h6c726b0_0

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to terminal and type:

```
pip install pandas
```

If that doesn't do it, you might have to install pip. try reinstalling Python but nsure that 'install pip' checkbox is checked (and environment variable checkbox too, that can be helpful)

Comment: No problem! You can use either, so if you're having problems with conda use pip and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't pip install into a conda environemnt if you don't have to!**

Try:

```
conda list pandas
```

and if conda can't find anything:

```
conda install pandas
```

Btw. how did you upgrade your Python to 3.8?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am guessing, but have you set up `$PYTHONPATH` and/or `$PYTHONHOME`? Delete

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.x:$PYTHONPATH
```

from your `~/.bash_profile` and restart.

Comment: No, conda and pip do basically the same. Please add this to your question and remove the pandas tag.

Comment: I suppose I had two already installed... maybe that's the problem

Comment: Could you please have a try with that solution?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I deleted python, conda, pip and installed python and conda from scratch.

Now everything works just fine!

Thanks for your help guys!